# Where does $f_n$ converge pointwise, is it uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_{n}:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of function defined by
$$
f_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
n(1-n x), & \text { if } 0<x<\frac{1}{n} \\
0, & \text { if } x=0 \text { or } \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1
\end{array}\right.
$$

The graph is a right triangle and when $n\to \infty$, triangle's basis vanishes. So can I say that this function converges pointwisely to $f(x)=0$?

If I can say that I can choose $$x=\dfrac{n-1}{n^2}\in (0,1/n)$$

For $\epsilon=1/2$, $\forall n\in \mathbb N^+$ $|f_n(x)-0|=1>\epsilon$

If I cannot assume the above pointwise assumption, how can I show it is not a Cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

You have the intuition for the pointwise convergence. But in order to give a *proof*, you need to show that for every $x\in[0,1]$,
$$
\lim_{n\to 0}f_n(x)=0
$$

One way to see that the sequence is not uniformly convergent is by observing that
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx=\frac12
$$
for all $n$ and that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=0$, where $f(x)\equiv 0$.

---

If you want to follow the definition of uniform convergence, you need to show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N$, there exist $x\in[0,1]$ and $n>N$ such that
$$
|f_n(x)-0|\ge \epsilon
$$